# Eliminate redundant Left in Either

Tags: scala

Given the code below that uses `Either` in two methods, is there a way to eliminate `case Left(error) => Left(error)` in the `duplicate` method as it simply passes through the `error` variable?

```
object HelloScala extends App{

   def duplicateAgain(a:Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future { 
       if (a>0) 
          Right(a*2)
       else
          Left("Error")
   }

   def duplicate(a: Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = {
       val future = duplicateAgain(a)
       future.map { either =>
         either match {
             case Right(response) => Right(response * 2)
             case Left(error) => Left(error)  // <-- this seems redundant
           }
       }
   }

    val future2 = duplicate(-1)
    future2.map { either =>
      either match {
        case Right(response) => println(response)
        case Left(error) => println(error)
      }
    }

    Thread.sleep(10000)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html#map[B1](f:B=%3EB1):scala.util.Either[A,B1]) - replace

```
either match {
    case Right(response) => Right(response * 2)
    case Left(error) => Left(error)  // <-- this seems redundant
}
```

with

```
either.map(response => response * 2)
```

As the documentation for `Either` says

> **Either** is right-biased, which means that **Right** is assumed to be the default case to operate on. If it is **Left**, operations like **map** and **flatMap** return the **Left** value unchanged